# Snapping middle vertex problem

Tags: snapping

I have seen many solutions, but non of them work.

I want to snap middle vertex signed with cursor to any of other vertex in the grid.

Box always snap to corner vertexes and I swear I have tried all the combination in snapping and transform option.

Snapping in *Edit Mode* or creating an empty is not the way or any pivot movements.

[image]

Comment: We can't really tell exactly what you want to do from your question or image. Could you please edit your question to describe exactly what you want and show an image of the whole Blender screen showing which settings you are using and how you want the snap to work.

Comment: Need to snap those two red vertexes.

Comment: This is a well known limitation of Blender snapping system, without addons, Blender can only snap to the bounding box.

Comment: Oh thanks, I didn't know that

Comment: Do you want to snap the plane to a vertex on the cube or the cube to the plane? - It's easy to snap the plane to the cube, but not the other way round as @DuarteFarrajotaRamos says.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set Snap.. **To**: 'Vertex' **With**: 'Center', and set the Transform Pivot Point to '3D Cursor', then you can use the 3D cursor as an intermediary. ('Center' then means '3D Cursor at the start of the move'.)

Working in Object Mode, with snap toggled off.

<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>RMB</kbd> - drag the 3D Cursor. Once the move is underway, you can release the <kbd>Shift</kbd>, and hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> to snap the Cursor to any source vertex you like.

This will be the point that is snapped to any target vertex you like..

So, holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, any vertex in the plane can be snapped to any vertex in the cube:

[image]

Or any vertex in the cube can be snapped to any vertex in the plane:

[image]

in Object Mode, or Edit Mode.

Comment: Thanks, your solution is great, Combination of Vertex Snap and Transform pivot to 3D cursor made the miracle. I don't even need to press ctrl. It snaps where the cursor was moved. Thanks